# Regular expression Modification

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have one asp.net application, in which i have one text box for URL. And i am using the regular expression for validating. My regular expression is like this:`^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$`

But now i have one enhancement like the text always keeps the text of **http://**. at that time the validation of this expression have to ignore the default text (http://). How it possible? Please help me by resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression matches the `http://` part, so it "keeps" that part of the match. If the text box you're validating doesn't contain that part at all, simply drop `(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/` from your regex.

If it is part of the text box, but you want to ignore it after having matched it, then you can put capturing parenthesess around your intended match. Your original regex would then look like this:

```
^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?)$
```

Now the part without `http://` or `ftp://` etc will be in backreference number 3.

That said, your regex as it stands now is pretty bad and also incorrect (lots of unnecessary escapes, unnecessary parentheses, wrongly constructed character classes (URLs with port number will fail here), and I'm pretty sure that you don't want `&amp;` in there)...

It is not easy to validate URLs with regexes. What are your intentions? What should be valid, what shouldn't be?

Comment: i want the expression for validating the after part of http://. Because the http// text is always displaying.

Comment: You mean that it is outside of the text box? Well then drop that part from the regex as outlined in the first sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

Use `((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)?` in the starting of your regular expression which makes http:// or ftp:// as optional.

Your complete regex would be -

```
^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)?[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$
```

Comment: But if it's there it will still be matched and therefore not ignored as Dilse Naaz is expecting it to be.

Comment: @Tim - I understood the question as matching the urls which dont have http:// etc. You may be right, in that case I think we need to remove `^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/)?` from the regex. But as you have mentioned, it will still be incorrect, because there are lot of other unnecessary escapes

Comment: Also I am not sure why does OP needs to ignore http:// from regex match. If its always available and if the current regex is working, why remove or ignore the http:// etc from regex. I dont think there is any performance related issues on this right?

Comment: your assumption is in correct way.. i want the expression for validating the after part of http://. Because the http// text is always displaying.

Comment: @Dilse - Not sure I understood correctly. You dont want to validate http:// right? then you can drop the first part as mentioned in my comment to Tim. Altough keeping this in regex also should not matter right? I am not understanding why you want to remove that http:// validation. Its always good to have it.